# Ability to connect 2 or more w5500 Modules and deal with them as objects

Tags: library, spi, ethernet, ethernet-shield, stm32

I wish to create a rudimentary ethernet in/out - switch/hub where I can (sort of) daisy chain my boards. (I don't wish to use a ethernet switch/router/hub)

- One port would be acting as server
- The other would be acting as a client
  (and forward any messages received on the first port after some processing/modification)

I am using an **STM32 Bluepill** with 2 Mini w5500 Modules (adafruit) connected via SPI. Nothing else is connected to SPI. All the other GPIOs are connected to relay drivers.

I use the Ethernet library. I have made sure they are connected to different CS pins and I have tried to assign `Ethernet.init();` before doing anything with specific Ethernet modules but that keeps disconnecting and is working very unreliably.

I understand that some modification in the library might be needed (I, by no means could figure out how and what).

References:

https://forum.arduino.cc/t/2-network-shields/111509
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/connect-multiple-ethernet-shields-to-arduino-uno-using-spi/284008/16

But no one seems to have gotten it to work. Please help.

Comment: it is not possible with the Arduino Ethernet library

Comment: Thanks @Juraj, I realized the same. Is there another way or has anyone modified this library to achieve this?

Comment: I would use a hub or Ethernet splitters. Ethernet wiring is a bus, but for practical reasons the bus was moved into hubs and  with that the topology looks like a start topology.  Then switches added optimized packets routing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet#Evolution

Comment: @Juraj Alright then, I feel it would be worth someone's while to modify the library for this, but for now I am convinced that the Arduino ethernet library isn't going to do it.